# Can I select * from a table comparing Column2 to (Column2 with the latest time stamp in Column1)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table example

```
Column1 (datetime)      Column2 (varchar)
-----------------------------------------
2-22-2022 1:11:11       1234-1
2-22-2022 1:12:11       1234-1
2-22-2022 1:13:11       4321-1
2-22-2022 1:14:11       4321-1
2-23-2022 7:00:00       4321-1
2-23-2022 7:02:00       4321-1
2-23-2022 7:04:00       4321-1
2-23-2022 7:10:00       1111-1
2-23-2022 7:11:00       1111-1
2-23-2022 7:12:00       1111-1
2-23-2022 7:13:00       1111-1
```

I am recording process data. The `Column2` number will repeat until the batch is finished, then a new number will record for the next batch. I would like to return the last two rows only in this example but the number of rows can very depending on the number of records.

I would like to return all rows with 1111-1 in `Column2`. There could be < or > 4 records.

Desired result

```
Column1 (datetime)      Column2 (varchar)    
-----------------------------------------
2-23-2022 7:10:00       1111-1
2-23-2022 7:11:00       1111-1
2-23-2022 7:12:00       1111-1
2-23-2022 7:13:00       1111-1
```

Comment: You should group your results using a Group By clause this will limit it to 1 row per grouping.

Comment: Do you mean you want to return the second and fourth row?

Comment: I would like to return all rows that have the same varchar as the row with the latest datetime.  The count will vary depending on the production batch size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get the two last rows for each batch then you may use:

```
with cte as
 (SELECT Column1, Column2, 
  rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column2 ORDER BY Column1 DESC)
  FROM Table)
 select Column1, Column2
 from cte
 where rowNum in (1, 2)
 order by Column1 desc
```

If you need to get the two last rows that have been inserted in the table then you may use:

```
SELECT TOP 2 Column1, Column2, 
      rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column2 ORDER BY Column1 DESC)
      FROM Table
ORDER BY Column1 desc
```

Also if you need to get rows with the same values then you mat use dense_rank() instead of row_number():

```
SELECT TOP 2 Column1, Column2, 
          rowNum = dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY Column2 ORDER BY Column1 DESC)
          FROM Table
    ORDER BY Column1 desc
```

Comment: What if I do not know the number of rows I need. I would like it to return all rows with the same characters in Column2. Column2 characters stay the same until a new batch is started.

Comment: @NathanGould then you need to use "dense_rank()" function instead of "row_number()" in the first my query. All rows with the same values get the same rank so you get desired result

Comment: Using "dense_rank()" I was able to complete my task. Thank You.

Comment: @NathanGould it's good news. It was a pleasure to help you. You may mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Nathan.

I suggest you take advantage of the ROW_NUMBER() windowing function which lets you number your rows segmented by changing values in a column and ordered by values in another column:

```
SELECT ic.Column1, ic.Column2
  FROM (SELECT Column1, 
               Column2, 
               rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column2 ORDER BY Column1 DESC)
          FROM YourTable) ic
 WHERE ic.rowNum <= 2
```

The inner query will return:

```
Column1(datetime)       Column2(varchar)    rowNum(int)
2-22-2022 1:11:11       1234                2
2-22-2022 1:12:11       1234                1
2-22-2022 1:13:11       4321                2
2-22-2022 1:14:11       4321                1
```

And if there were MORE rows for values in Column2, then  earlier rows would get HIGHER rowNum values (due to the ORDER BY ... DESC).

The outer query, by using `WHERE ic.rowNum <= 2`, will only render the last two rows per value in Column2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   Col1,
   Col2
FROM
Table 
GROUP BY Col1,Col2
ORDER By Col1 DESC
```

You can do a Count(*) as Volume to see how many iterations each batch had.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's too much emphasis on trying to count the number of rows in these other answers.  It really doesn't matter how many rows there are. The original request specified that he wants ALL the records from a particular table where the condition was met.  What he needs is first to determine the value of Column1 of the newest record which could be found using:

Select max(Column1)
from table

He then can get the value of column2 of that records using:

Select Column2
from table
where Column1 = (select max(Column1) from table)

Now to put it all together to get all records in the table where Column2 contains the same value of the newest record, use:

Select *
from table
where Column2 = (select Column2 from table where Column1 = (select max(column1) from table))